# HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync está limitando a 2 chamadas simultaneas

Tags: c#, winforms

Possuo uma aplicação onde os clientes podem baixar pacotes que são arquivos .zip com média de 1Gb.

Ao iniciar um download, é criada uma nova thread que fará a requisição e via stream resgata parte dos bytes e vai escrevendo em um arquivo.

O problema é:

Inicio o primeiro download e funciona corretamente.

Inicio o segundo e também funciona corretamente, os dois downloads rodam simultaneamente.

Porém quando inicio o terceiro, a execução da nova thread fica parada esperando a resposta no comando GetResponseAsync() (LINHA 35), caso eu pause algum dos downloads anteriores ai sim o código continua, provavelmente porque uma das instâncias WebResponse que o GetResponseAsync retornou é fechada.

Preciso que seja possível fazer o download de vários pacotes ao mesmo tempo.

O método responsável pelo download:

```
    private async void DownloadPackage()
    {
        FileStream fileStream = null;

        try
        {
            string appDataPath = GetAppDataPath();
            int currentIndex = 0;
            int bytesReceived = 0;
            int currentRateBytes = 0;
            long bytesSaved = 0;

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(GetPackageUrl()));

            if (File.Exists(appDataPath))
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(appDataPath);
                fileStream = File.Open(appDataPath, FileMode.Append);
                bytesSaved = fileInfo.Length;
                req.AddRange(bytesSaved);
            }
            else if (File.Exists(GetZipPackagePath()))
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(appDataPath))
                    Directory.Delete(appDataPath, true);

                File.Move(GetZipPackagePath(), appDataPath);
                PreparePresentation();
                DownloadCompleted();
                return;
            }
            else
                fileStream = File.Create(appDataPath);

            using (WebResponse response = await req.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                long contentLength = response.ContentLength;

                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    DateTime lastRateUpdate = DateTime.Now;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2560];

                    while (currentIndex < contentLength)
                    {
                        if (!continueDownload)
                        {
                            DownloadPaused();
                            break;
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            bytesReceived = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 2560);
                            currentRateBytes += bytesReceived;
                            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
                            fileStream.Flush();
                            currentIndex += bytesReceived;
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            if (tryCount == 5)
                            {
                                string msg = string.Format("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar fazer download do pacote, verifique sua conexão e tente novamente.\nErro: {0}", e.Message);
                                MessageBox.Show(msg);
                                tryCount = 0;
                                continueDownload = false;
                                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                                {
                                    NeedDownload();
                                });
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                tryCount++;
                                fileStream.Close();
                                response.Close();
                                DownloadPackage(new object(), new EventArgs());
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;

                        if ((DateTime.Now - lastRateUpdate).TotalSeconds >= 2)
                        {
                            DownloadRate rate = CalculateRate(lastRateUpdate, endTime, currentIndex, contentLength, currentRateBytes);
                            double percentage = (double)(currentIndex + bytesSaved) / (contentLength + bytesSaved);
                            UpdateProgressBar((int)(percentage * 100), rate);
                            lastRateUpdate = DateTime.Now;
                            currentRateBytes = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    fileStream.Close();
                }

                response.Close();

                if (continueDownload && PreparePresentation())
                    DownloadCompleted();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string msg;
            if(fileStream != null) fileStream.Close();

            if (e is WebException && ((HttpWebResponse)((WebException)e).Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable)
            {
                try 
                {
                    if(PreparePresentation()) DownloadCompleted();
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    msg = string.Format("Ocorreu um erro ao finalizar pacote.\nErro: {0}", e.StackTrace);
                    MessageBox.Show(msg, e.Message);
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        NeedDownload();
                    });
                    return;
                }
            }

            msg = string.Format("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar fazer download do pacote, verifique sua conexão e tente novamente.\nErro: {0}", e.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(msg, "Erro");
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                NeedDownload();
            });
        }
    }
```

Chamada do método:

```
    private void DownloadPackage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //algumas verificações
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(DownloadPackage);
        new Thread(ts).Start();
    }
```

Obs: Esses métodos estão dentro de um UserControl para cada pacote disponível.
Nesse UserControl possuem botões (para iniciar e pausar o download), barra de progresso, imagens, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) para aumentar o limite the conexões *outbound* que você pode fazer no seu processo. Se você aumentar esse valor. O valor default é 2, o que explica o que você está observando.

Comment: Perfeito cara, funcionou. Valeu pela ajuda.